# Some Angular objects do not have a value for a property

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building an app in Angular2 and have a question about how to structure my main class.

I need to create 78 instances of a class. The catch is that not all 78 share the same properties. They share everything but one property. Let's pretend this property is colour. Half of them have a value for colour, half of them don't.

Would you:

A) Divide them into two classes? *This seems clunky to me*

B) Use a colour decorator and pass those with a colour through the decorator? *I think this is the right solution, but I need clarification*

C) Something I haven't thought of?

Comment: TypeScript or JavaScript?

Comment: You have to be more specific. If your objects have different properties, they are different classes. If they share the same properties, but part of them don't have some of the properties, you can mark them as optional and never instantiate those properties.

Comment: I am confused how is this question related to Angular. Seems like a pure TypeScript quesion to me.

Comment: Updated my question to include TypeScript as a tag.

Answer (score 6):

Can you declare colour as optional? Declare it as something like `colour?: string`.

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html for some more info.

Comment: Fabulous! Thank you!

Comment: This is exactly how we do it.